# An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.11)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a rails  beginner,and I get a demo from https://github.com/rubytaiwan/jobs.ruby.tw

but when I try to run this demo,I got an error.

I run follow

```
bundle
```

I got the error

```
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.11), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.
```

but I can sure I have install mysql2

and the `Gemfile` is

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "1.9.3"

gem 'rails', '~> 3.2.12'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'devise', '~>2.1.3'
gem 'mysql2'

gem "babosa"
gem "rails_autolink"

gem "settingslogic"
gem "seo_helper"
gem 'open_graph_helper'
gem 'google_plus_helper'

gem 'exception_notification'

gem "mobile-fu"

gem 'capistrano', :group => "development"

gem 'rake', :group => :test

group :development do
  gem "capistrano"
  gem "magic_encoding"
  gem "annotate"
end

group :test, :development do
  gem "rspec"
  gem "rspec-rails"
  gem "simplecov"
  gem "capybara"
end
```

then I try to comment this row:

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

but I still got the error.
so I do not know why this error occurs

Comment: Windows or Linux or OSX?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

try it

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev
```

Comment: @RicardoMasaoShigeoka if you installed mysql using homebrew: I got it working with `brew link mysql` before installing the gem

Answer (score 5):

@Ricardo Masao Shigeoka for the mac ,try first

`brew install mysql`, then

Put in your Gemfile  `gem 'mysql2', '0.3.18'`

run `bundle` command in terminal.

This setup worked for me, I have El Captain OS, rails 4.2.6, hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

Try this one

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.4.10'
```